# Most efficient way to find an entry in a C++ vector

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vectors

I'm trying to construct an output table containing 80 rows of table status, that could be `EMPTY` or `USED` as below

```
+-------+-------+
| TABLE | STATE |
+-------+-------+
|  00   | USED  |
|  01   | EMPTY |
|  02   | EMPTY | 
..
..
|  79   | EMPTY |
+-------+-------+
```

I have a vector `m_availTableNums` which contains a list of available table numbers. In the below example, I'm putting 20 random table numbers into the above vector such that all the remaining 60 would be empty. My logic below works fine.

Is there a scope for improvement here on the find logic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_availTableNums;
    char tmpStr[50];

    uint8_t tableNum;
    uint8_t randomCount;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for( tableNum=0; tableNum < 20; tableNum++ )
    {
        randomCount = ( rand() % 80 );
        m_availTableNums.push_back( randomCount );
    }

    sprintf(tmpStr, "+-------+-------+");
    printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
    tmpStr[0]='\0';

    sprintf(tmpStr, "| TABLE | STATE |");
    printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
    tmpStr[0]='\0';

    sprintf(tmpStr, "+-------+-------+");
    printf("%s\n", tmpStr);

    tableNum = 0;
    for( tableNum=0; tableNum < 80 ; tableNum++ )
    {
        tmpStr[0]='\0';
        if ( std::find(m_availTableNums.begin(), m_availTableNums.end(), tableNum) != m_availTableNums.end() )
        {
            sprintf(tmpStr, "|  %02d   | EMPTY |", tableNum );
        } else {
            sprintf(tmpStr, "|  %02d   | USED  |", tableNum );
        }

        printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
    }

    tmpStr[0]='\0';
    sprintf(tmpStr, "+-------+-------+");
    printf("%s\n", tmpStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that hardcoded 80 a coincidence (i.e. could be other numbers, too) or by design? Because if that's by design and if you really only want to know taken-or-not-taken, a `std::bitset<80>` will do, too. This will not only be idiomatic, but also faster than any other solution. A bitset of that size fits in two quadwords, or one cache line, respectively. No runtime allocations (while inserting without having called `reserve()` like you do). Access is constant, single assembly instruction, it doesn't get easier or faster than that.

Comment: @Damon It’s important to remember that not every machine is an x86 computer; many embedded systems for example use 8- or 16-bit processors and have no cache.

Comment: @Edward: C++11 pretty much rules out 8- or 16-bit embedded systems, but yes in general you are right. Though a bit set worth 5 16-bit words will still be an order of magnitude more efficient to access than iterating a `std::vector` even on a no-cache machine.

Comment: In fact, `g++` has supported 8-bit AVR processors for some years.  I have `g++ 7.2.0` for AVR on my main computer right now and it supports C++17 on that platform.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Header files

It's strange that this code uses the C header `<string.h>` but the C++ versions of `<cmath>`, `<ctime>` and `<cstdlib>`.  I recommend sticking to the C++ headers except on the rare occasions that you need to compile the same code with a C compiler.  In this case, I don't see anything using `<cstring>`, so we can probably just drop that, along with `<iomanip>`, `<iostream>` and `<cmath>`.  And we need to add some missing includes: `<cstdint>` and `<cstdio>`.

## Avoid `using namespace std`

The standard namespace is not one that's designed for wholesale import like this.  Unexpected name collisions when you add another header or move to a newer C++ could even cause changes to the meaning of your program.

## Use the appropriate signature for `main()`

Since we're ignoring the command-line arguments, we can use a `main()` that takes no parameters:

```
int main()
```

## Remove pointless temporary string

Instead of formatting into `tmpStr` and immediately printing its contents to standard output, we can eliminate that variable by formatting directly to standard output (using the same format string).  For example, instead of:

> ```
> std::sprintf(tmpStr, "+-------+-------+");
> std::printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
> tmpStr[0]='\0';
>
> std::sprintf(tmpStr, "| TABLE | STATE |");
> std::printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
> tmpStr[0]='\0';
>
> std::sprintf(tmpStr, "+-------+-------+");
> std::printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
> ```

we could simply write:

```
std::puts("+-------+-------+\n"
          "| TABLE | STATE |\n"
          "+-------+-------+");
```

And instead of

> ```
>     tmpStr[0]='\0';
>     if ( std::find(m_availTableNums.begin(), m_availTableNums.end(), tableNum) != m_availTableNums.end() )
>     {
>         std::sprintf(tmpStr, "|  %02d   | EMPTY |", tableNum );
>     } else {
>         std::sprintf(tmpStr, "|  %02d   | USED  |", tableNum );
>     }
>
>     printf("%s\n", tmpStr);
> ```

we would have:

```
    if (std::find(m_availTableNums.begin(), m_availTableNums.end(), tableNum) != m_availTableNums.end()) {
        std::printf("|  %02d   | EMPTY |\n", tableNum);
    } else {
        std::printf("|  %02d   | USED  |\n", tableNum);
    }
```

## Reduce duplication

Most of these statements are common:

> ```
>         std::printf("|  %02d   | EMPTY |\n", tableNum);
>     } else {
>         std::printf("|  %02d   | USED  |\n", tableNum);
>     }
> ```

The only bit that's different is the `EMPTY` or `USED` string.  So let's decide that first:

```
    const char *status =
        std::find(m_availTableNums.begin(), m_availTableNums.end(), tableNum) != m_availTableNums.end()
        ? "EMPTY" : "USED";
    std::printf("|  %02d   | %-5s |\n", tableNum, status);
```

## Prefer `nullptr` value to `NULL` macro

The C++ null pointer has strong type, whereas `NULL` or `0` can be interpreted as integer.

## Reduce scope of variables

`randomCount` doesn't need to be valid outside the first `for` loop, and we don't need to use the same `tableNum` for both loops.  Also, we could follow convention and use a short name for a short-lived loop index; `i` is the usual choice:

```
for (std::uint8_t i = 0;  i < 20;  ++i) {
    std::uint8_t randomCount = rand() % 80;
    m_availTableNums.push_back(randomCount);
}
```

```
for (std::uint8_t i = 0;  i < 80;  ++i) {
```

## Avoid magic numbers

What's special about `80`?  Could we need a different range?  Let's give the constant a name, and then we can be sure that the loop matches this range:

```
constexpr std::uint8_t LIMIT = 80;
...
    std::uint8_t randomCount = rand() % LIMIT;
...
for (std::uint8_t i = 0;  i < LIMIT;  ++i) {
```

## A departure from specification

The description says

> I'm putting 20 random table numbers into the above vector such that, all the remaining 60 would be empty.

That's not exactly what's happening, as we're sampling *with replacement* from the values 0..79.  There's nothing to prevent duplicates being added (it's actually quite unlikely that there will be exactly 60 empty values).

## Reduce the algorithmic complexity

Each time through the loop, we use `std::find()` to see whether we have any matching elements.  This is a *linear* search, so it examines elements in turn until it finds a match.  Since it only finds a match one-quarter of the time, the other three-quarters will examine *every element in the list*, and the time it takes will be proportional to the list length - we say it scales as O(*n*), where *n* is the size of the vector.  The complete loop therefore scales as O(*mn*), where *m* is the value of `LIMIT`.

We can reduce the complexity to O(*m* + *n*) if we use some extra storage to store the values in a way that makes them easy to test.  For example, we could populate a vector that's indexed by the values from `m_availTableNums`:

```
auto by_val = std::vector<bool>(LIMIT, false);
for (auto value: m_availTableNums)
    by_val[value] = true;

for (std::uint8_t i = 0;  i < LIMIT;  ++i) {
    const char *status = by_val[i] ? "EMPTY" : "USED";
    std::printf("|  %02d   | %-5s |\n", i, status);
}
```

If the range were much larger, we might use an (unordered) set instead of `vector<bool>`.  We might also choose `vector<char>` instead of `vector<bool>` for better speed at a cost of more space.

---

## Simplified code

Here's my version, keeping to the spirit of the original (creating a list of indices, rather than changing to storing in the form we want to use them):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::uint8_t LIMIT = 80;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> m_availTableNums;

    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

    for (std::uint8_t i = 0;  i < 20;  ++i) {
        std::uint8_t randomCount = rand() % LIMIT;
        m_availTableNums.push_back(randomCount);
    }

    std::puts("+-------+-------+\n"
              "| TABLE | STATE |\n"
              "+-------+-------+");

    auto by_val = std::vector<bool>(LIMIT, false);
    for (auto value: m_availTableNums)
        by_val[value] = true;

    for (std::uint8_t i = 0;  i < LIMIT;  ++i) {
        const char *status = by_val[i] ? "EMPTY" : "USED";
        std::printf("|  %02d   | %-5s |\n", i, status);
    }

    std::puts("+-------+-------+");
}
```

Comment: Excellent points! `++`, I do have to let know that I'm not an expert yet in C++, just in the beginner stages. These points are really useful. One question before I accept this answer. Your opinion on dave's comment above to use sort and remove elements at head?

Comment: That's a possibility - in complexity terms, that's similar to my suggestion.  To some extent, the best choice may depend on whether modifying the values is acceptable.  If you go with the sorting, don't forget that you may need to remove multiple elements from the head of the vector when there are duplicate values in it (oh, and don't actually remove - that's expensive; just advance over them and leave them in place).

Comment: ```The only thing tmpStr is ever used for is to immediately pass it to printf() with a %s format. So why not just printf() directly?``` - first make sure the string doesn't contain any characters with a special meaning for printf

Comment: @hanshenrik, perhaps I didn't word that very well.  I meant we should replace the `sprintf` into `tmpStr` with a `printf` directly to standard output - same (or nearly same) format string.  I'll see if I can edit to prevent misunderstandings.

Comment: Instead of `printf` and `sprintf` would `std::cout` and `std::ostringstream` be better choices?

Comment: @TheLoneMilkMan - not automatically: I think that the use here of fixed-with conversions is much simpler using `<cstdio>`.  One could take a different approach - and if you do, I encourage you to write it up as an answer of your own (it sounds like it may well be worth considering).

Comment: Switching the format-string instead of the inset (`EMPTY` / `FULL `) is slightly simpler and more efficient. Yes, it isn't *quite* as DRY, but only marginally.

Comment: Minor nit: a constant known at compile time can be `constexpr`, not just `static const`.

Comment: @Davislor: quite right (I was thinking that `constexpr` required C++14; it's getting hard to keep track of changes now).

Comment: @Deduplicator: "simpler" is subjective, and I think I disagree with you there.  You're probably right on the "more efficient" bit, though.  (I find it ironic, given your handle, that you're the one arguing for duplication!)

Comment: @TobySpeight Excess is always bad, and that went marginally above my personal threshold, especially as it would hinder i18n (unlikely to be an issue as it is). Certainly concurr about the irony.

Comment: One word: iterators.  When you're looping through all elements of a vector, using an iterator will be faster instead of indexing into the vector each time.  With raw arrays there are times that direct indexing can be faster, if the compiler can do some loop unrolling, but this is an exception and generally it's faster to loop a pointer through the array.  With vectors, I don't believe any compiler can do loop unrolling, so iterators should always be preferred.

Comment: @Graham, have you compared the generated code using iterators and using indices?  Decent optimising compilers will transform indexing operations into pointer operations quite routinely.

Answer (score 8):

I would seriously consider whether std::vector is the right data structure. Do you need the available table numbers to be in the order you got them, or can they be sorted? Do you need to allow duplicate table numbers? (I.e. if I add 42 twice, do I have one entry for 42 or two?)

If the data can be sorted and de-duplicated, then the most efficient way to find an entry is to store the data in a std::set. Storing the data takes a little longer (O(log n) for the set vs. amortized O(1) for the vector), but finding the data makes up for it (O(log n) for the set vs. O(n) for the vector). If you use a set, make sure to use set's find function (e.g. `mySet.find(tableNum)` rather than `std::find(mySet.begin(),mySet.end(),tableNum)`), or there's no benefit.

On a more general code-style note, since you're using C++ data structures anyway, you should probably use `std::string` and `std::cout` instead of `char *`/`char[]` and `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

A `std::set` or `std::bitset` might be the better containers to use for this, but assuming we're going to stick with `std::vector`, here's some improvements on this.

See Toby Speight's answer for some of the improvements I used but did not cover.

### Avoid using unsigned numbers

Don't use `unsigned int` or `uint8_t`. Counterintuitively, it's generally best to use signed `int` types even when a value should never be negative. Operations on mixed signed types come with a lot of problems. It's an unfortunate mistake the standard went with unsigned numbers for container sizes. Unsigned numbers are best kept to bitwise operations.

### Store whether an index is used at that index

Instead of storing a list of indexes that have been used, let's just store a `bool` at each possible index. This uses more space, but then no extra searching has to be done, just a single loop. (Notice I've changed `m_availTableNums` to `availTableNums`. The prefix `m_` is conventionally only used for class members).

```
std::vector<bool> availTableNums (80);
```

Putting the 80 here will initialize the vector with 80 false values. Now when we fill the table, we choose random indices to insert `true` which indicates a value of used.

```
std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
{
    availTableNums[std::rand() % availTableNums.size()] = true;
}
```

### Using modern RNG facilities

`std::rand` has no guarantees of the "randomness" of the numbers it generates. It's fine if you want to run up a quick test, but in production code we could modify the previous example to make it a little more robust.

```
std::default_random_engine engine {std::time()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> uniform_dist {0, availTableNums.size()};
for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
{
    availTableNums[uniform_dist(e1)] = true;
}
```

Here we use `std::size_t`, even though it's an unsigned type, as it is better to not have to cast from one type to another if we could avoid it. The random number generator will automatically pick from the correct range so we no longer need the modulus operator.

### Use C++ string streams

There is no need for a temporary string, and C++ streams are often a better choice than the C printf family of functions. We can write the header of the table as:

```
std::cout << "+-------+-------+\n"
          << "| TABLE | STATE |\n"
          << "+-------+-------+" << std::endl;
```

The extra `<<`s are left for style but not necessary. Now for the printing inside the loop, use `std::setw(2)` to make sure the printed index is within 2 columns. The value of this resets if string is sent to `std::cout` so it will not effect the rest of the line.

The use of `std::endl` will cause the output to always be flushed from the buffer and will have a small performance penalty. However, I am usually quite generous with them unless it is shown they have a sizeable impact on performance. It can make code easier to debug if output is consistently flushed and you know exactly where something went wrong.

```
for(auto i=0u; i < availTableNums.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << "|  " << std::setw(2) << i << "   | "
              << (availTableNums[i] ? "USED " : "EMPTY")
              << " |" << std::endl;
}
```

We again choose an unsigned index as comparing two unsigned types is better than comparing mixed signs or casting one to the other. The conditional expression `?:` allows us to concisely choose between the two strings depending on whether the index is true or false.

---

Putting it all together with only the relavent headers, we get:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> availTableNums (80);

    std::default_random_engine engine {std::time()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> uniform_dist {0, availTableNums.size()};
    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        availTableNums[uniform_dist(e1)] = true;
    }

    std::cout << "+-------+-------+\n"
              << "| TABLE | STATE |\n"
              << "+-------+-------+" << std::endl;

    for(auto i=0u; i < availTableNums.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "|  " << std::setw(2) << i << "   | "
                  << (availTableNums[i] ? "USED " : "EMPTY")
                  << " |" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "+-------+-------+" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 `Avoid using unsigned numbers`: Really good advice. Hard to get across especially with `std::size_t` being unsigned but you addressed that point well.

Comment: Avoid advising using `std::endl`. Do he really need to pay for a flush? Furthermore, in your  `TABLE | STATE` you can safely keep the 1rst `<<` and remove others.

Comment: I'd consider the unsigned numbers a preference thing.  There are some *very* strong reasons to use unsigned numbers.  To call their use a "mistake" in the STL suggests you haven't thought those through.

Comment: @Calak - I put in a note about the performance penalty, but haven't been convinced it's always that bad. I left the extra `<<` in as a style choice but I could probably note that.

Comment: @CortAmmon - Well I'm basing that off of the opinion of Stroustrup and others involved in the STL design. I'm aware there's not a consensus but the issue isn't usually brought up enough.

Answer (score 2):

The above are good advice. Do you need **exactly** N values true? If so, the above loop might be better as (pieces left out for simplicity):

```
const std::size_t N = 80;
const std::size_t K = 20;

std::unordered_set<std::size_t> exists;

// Fill exists with K random values between [0 .. N], inclusive.
std::default_random_engine rng{std::time()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> uniform_dist {0, N};
while (exists.size() < K) {
  exists.insert(uniform_dist(rng));
}

// Print each value in order, in a table.
for(auto i = uniform_dist.min(); i <= uniform_dist.max(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "|  " << std::setw(2) << i << "   | "
              << ((exists.count(i) == 0) ?  "EMPTY" : "USED ")
              << " |" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: (Nice catch, with the exception of picking the symbolic name for the total number in your question about the requirements instead of that for the "true sub-set".)